# Where should we maintain external (subcontractors) usernames and passwords?

Tags: active-directory, credentials, domain

We have three environments:

- Testing and development
- Preproduction
- Production

In our company all technical people, including sysadmins and network administrators, are subcontractors so a lot of them (but not all) need access to almost everything.

**Where should we maintain external (subcontractors) credentials?**

Today we have a different domains for them, one different domain por each environment: "EXTERNALSTEST", "EXTERNALSPRE" and "EXTERNALSPRO" (we also have domains for our own employees ("COMPANYTEST", "COMPANYPRE" and "COMPANYPRO").

We also give different usernames to externals depending on the environment:
test_username for "Testing and Development environment" and "Preproduction" environments and username for "Production" environment.

We are looking for doing this easier but secure.

**Can we have a unique username and a unique domain "EXTERNALS" stored in "Production" for all external employees?**

The risk I see here is that if we have the EXTERNAL domain just in Production we will have to open the communication from the other environments to Production and today we have a good segregation of this environments with firewalls rules.

**Is this the better organization of external users? Is this secure?**

Comment: With "unique" username, do you mean "just one", e.g. every external user shares the same username? If so, DON'T do this. This would make it impossible to know who did what based on logs you keep, and might make it impossible to bring legal action against an individual if necessary.

Comment: @Pascal Each external user has two usernames: iusername (for integration and preproduction environment) and username for production. My question is wether we could have only one username (one for each external user) for all environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a network architect, but a red teamer. The networks that have been the hardest from a password management and segregation perspective have been that of administrators needing a user account and an administrator account. So if they are external, they would use their user account with two factor authentication to access the vpn for the environment they need. After accessing the VPN via two factor auth, they would need to access the password vault to "check out" their administrative credentials. Lieberman seems to be a decent option. I would also require two factor authentication to the password vault with a different soft/hard token. After the admins check out their password and then are done with them, have the passwords change, I know Lieberman does this errrr lol. This will HELP mitigate the possibility of the credentials being obtained from memory, cache, secrets, etc.

I think the segregation of domains is good, make sure to check the trust relationship between them. The different domains should not have any established trusts (regardless of what anyone says), otherwise what is the point of a different domain? Here is a link to the Lieberman website that give an in-depth description on how they try and mitigate attack on credentials: https://liebsoft.com/products/enterprise_random_password_manager/

As to the option of using LDAP and Kerberos on the internet...please...do not do that... I don't have enough points to respond to the comment directly. I read through the documentation that was provided: first of all it does not seem to offer the ability to use 2 factor authentication, which is horrible in itself but even more so when you are asking for a solution used primarily by administrators. Also, I just looked and it offers the administrative console for user and authentication management on the internet, with a simple admin username and password. This would leave it susceptible to brute force all day...keys to the kingdom. Some may say you don't have to put them on the internet, however it looks like most "MarkLogic" servers are from a simple shodan search. It looks sketchy at best.

I can say from experience that 2 factor authentication creates a huge headache and disturbance for hackers during their operations. Especially when its coupled with good password management of administrative credentials, i.e. the creds change frequently, are different from the user credentials, and another barrier of 2 factor auth is required to even access them.

ALSO!!!!! Do not let the soft token be requested and automatically approved by the user that is requesting them, AKA a self service portal for soft tokens. That needs to be a manual validation process. I do not believe this is a complete solution, however a good start. Hope this perspective helps at any rate.

Comment: About this sentence: "As to the option of using LDAP and Kerberos on the internet...please...do not do that...". Do you recommend to not use LDAP for storing credentials for applications that login from Internet? What should we use? A regular database? Or do you agree in using LDAP but with different credentials from the domain? Different credencials for access from Internet and internal access?